# Cannot update the user.last_login field

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am using Django 1.11 and `User` model from `django.contrib.auth`.

Here's my code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
u = User.objects.create_user('user1')
print(u.last_login) # prints old date
u.last_login = timezone.now()
u.save()
u.refresh_from_db() # just in case
print(u.last_login) # prints old date
```

Why does the `last_login` field not get updated?

Comment: can you check `print(u.last_login)` before `u.refresh_from_db()` once?

Comment: @NoobEditor Just tried, it's still the old value.

Comment: no errors or anything? are you executing it via '.py' file or shell?

Comment: I'm executing in django shell `python manage.py shell`, I don't think it makes a difference though.

Comment: What is your *actual* code that isn't working? Your comment `# prints old date` doesn't make sense -- `last_login` would be `None` after creating the user.

Comment: @Alasdair Yes you are right, by old date I mean `None`. I expect django to set the `last_login` field after assigning it and saving the user object, but it doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: Your code looks fine. I think you'll need to add more information about how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Alasdair Ok It turns out I had a signal receiver which was modifying `last_login`. Add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad you found the problem. It would be better for you to add an answer that shows what the signal was and how you fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had a signal receiver like this elsewhere in the code which was messing up the `last_login` field:

```
@receiver(models.signals.pre_save, sender=User)
def by_pass_save_last_login(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    u = User.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    if not instance.last_login:
        instance.last_login = timezone.now()
    else:
        instance.last_login = u.last_login
```

It was loading the user from the database and since it's `last_login` is `None` it was setting that value to the user instance.

Fixing this receiver fixed the problem:

```
@receiver(models.signals.pre_save, sender=User)
def by_pass_save_last_login(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.last_login:
        instance.last_login = timezone.now()
```

Comment: @NoobEditor I have to wait 2 days to assure my answer

Comment: hmmm...SO can be brutal sometimes! :D